# What causes this System.IO.FileNotFoundException in ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, filenotfoundexception

I have a desktop application which requires a report viewer application to print a file. I am getting an exception at runtime even after installing the application version 2005, 2008, and 2010.

```
Error :  
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly  

   'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     
  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

I have installed Report Viewer 2005, 2008, and 2010, but I do not see any improvement and I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Note: There is a `'data.dll`' file in my application which handles the printing job and it dependent on reportviewer dll files, but i am not aware about the internal functioning of `data.dll` file

Answer (score 0):

ensure that Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms with the Version 9.0.0.0 is either installed

- in the GAC (open with the windows explorer the folder %SystemRoot%\assembly, often C:\Windows\assemly) or
- in the folder of your application